# My insert method isn't working

Tags: javascript, c#, dapper

I'm using dapper to map my database with my mvc project, i have debugged my code to know what's going on and my ReceiveData method isn't receiving the data for some reason when it sends it to my GeoCreate it shows nothing, also i might me wrong because i placed my cursor on my Geo.RouteID, Geo.Latitude,etc and the data was there then it goes to my geography class and after that it's supposed to go to the if statement but it stops there, i'm sending json data with postman.

Here's my ReceiveData method

```
public bool ReceiveData(Geography Geo)
{
    int GeoCreate = this.conn.Execute(@"INSERT GEOGRAPHY([ID_ROUTE],[LAT],[LONG],[BATTERY],[DateCreated],[DEVICE_ID]) values (@Lat,@Long,@Battery,@DateCreated,@Device_ID)",
                    new { RouteID = Geo.RouteID, Lat = Geo.Latitude, Long = Geo.Longitude, Battery = Geo.Battery, DateCreated = Geo.ObtainedDate, DeviceID = Geo.Device_ID });

    if(GeoCreate > 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Here's the action for calling the ReceiveData method:

```
[Route("GeoCreate")]
[HttpPost]
public bool StoreLocation(Geography Geo)
{
    return GD.ReceiveData(Geo);
}
```

Here's the javascript code that works for sending my data:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Geograph = {
            Latitude: $("#Latitude").val(),
            Longitude: $("#Longitude").val(),
            Country: $("#Country").val(),
            ObtainedDate: $("#ObtainedDate").val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("StoreLocation", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.parse( { Geo: Geograph }),
            success: function (lctn) {
                console.log(lctn);
                debugger;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And my Geography class:

```
public class Geography
{
    [Key]
    public int RouteID { get; set; }

    public double Latitude { get; set; }

    public double Longitude { get; set; }

    public int Battery { get; set; }

    public DateTime ObtainedDate { get; set; }

    public int Device_ID { get; set; }

}
```

Here's the JSON data i'm sending:

```
{
    "Latitude": 19.435547,
    "Longitude": -81.77856,
    "Battery": 100,
    "ObtainedDate":"\/Date(1522600449000)\/",
    "Device_ID": 1
}
```

I'm not setting the RouteID because it fills automatically in the database.

Comment: Can you add to your question the JSON you are sending? Also, if you debug and look at the `ModelState` property in the action (when the breakpoint hints `return GD.ReceiveData(Geo);`) it should tell you what's wrong with the input data

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto done, the data appears in my return GD.ReceiveData(Geo); the problem is after that when it calls the method it should go to the if statement but it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

In your *ajax* call you should use `JSON.stringify` rather than `parse` method

```
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("StoreLocation", "Home")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: JSON.stringify( { Geo: Geograph }),
            success: function (lctn) {
                console.log(lctn);
                debugger;

            }
    });
```

Comment: Originally i was using JSON.stringify, i changed it to parse because i use to send it to a JsonResult method before